# Regex get group block with specific start and end each group

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

If we had some string like :

```
----------DBVer=1
/*some sql script*/
----------DBVer=1
----------DBVer=2
/*some sql script*/
----------DBVer=2
----------DBVer=n
/*some sql script*/
----------DBVer=n
```

Can we extract scripts between first DBVer=1 and second DBVer=1 and so on... with regex?

I thing we must have some placehoder for regex, and tel regex engine if saw DBVer=digitA pick string until DBVer=digitA again if saw DBVer=digitB pick string until DBVer=digitB and so on...

Can we implement this with regex and if we can how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using backreferences and lookarounds, you can capture the scripts:

```
var pattern = @"(?<=(?<m>-{10}DBVer=\d+)\r?\n).*(?=\r?\n\k<m>)";
var scripts = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline)
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value);
```

Here, we capture the `m` (marker) group with `(?<m>-{10}DBVer=\d+)` and reuse the `m` value later in the regex with `\k<m>` to match against the end marker.

In order for `.*` to match newline chars, it is necessary to turn on `Singleline` mode. This, in turn, means we have to be specific about our newlines. In `Singleline` mode, these can be accounted for in a non-platform specific way with `\r?\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below.  Not RegEx but works very well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Script.ReadScripts(FILENAME);   
        }
    }
    public class Script
    {
        enum State
        {
            Get_Script,
            Read_Script
        }

        public static List<Script> scripts = new List<Script>();
        public int version { get; set; }
        public string script { get; set; }

        public static void ReadScripts(string filename)
        {
            string inputLine = "";
            string pattern = "DBVer=(?'version'\\d+)";
            State state = State.Get_Script;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            Script newScript = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.Get_Script :
                            if(inputLine.StartsWith("-----"))
                            {
                                newScript = new Script();
                                scripts.Add(newScript);
                                string version = 
                                  Regex.Match(inputLine, pattern).Groups["version"].Value;
                                newScript.version = int.Parse(version);
                                newScript.script = "";
                                state = State.Read_Script;
                            }
                            break;
                        case State.Read_Script :
                            if (inputLine.StartsWith("-----"))
                            {
                                state = State.Get_Script;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (newScript.script.Length == 0)
                                {
                                    newScript.script = inputLine;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    newScript.script += "\n" + inputLine;
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```